# How to convert lambda function into a next.js api friendly function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, next.js

I have a Instagram api making calls to my personal profile and ran as a lambda function from netlify which goes like this:

```
require('isomorphic-unfetch')

const url = `https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/...`

async function getPosts() {...}

exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {
   const posts = await getPosts()
   callback(null, {
       statusCode: 200,
       headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       },
       body: JSON.stringify(posts),
   })
}
```

I am rebuilding the site using Next.js and migrating my site to vercel and want to run the serverless function from /pages/api/insta.js but Next.js throws an error as it expects something along the lines of :

```
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

// export default (req, res) => {
//   res.statusCode = 200
//   res.json({ name: 'John Doe' })
// }
```

Comment: Have you tried converting it to the new format? What specific issues have you got?

Comment: I don't know anything abut formats so just wanted someone to convert the exports.handler bit and potentially offer some guidance as to what becomes whom...

Comment: Just wondering what this has to do with next.js?

Answer (score 0):

Ok lads, managed to resolve the issue by conversion to the following code - posting it in case someone else comes across the same issue:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const posts = await getPosts()
    res.statusCode = 200
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.end(JSON.stringify(posts))
}
```